# Array multiples PHP

Tags: php, json, webservice, api

hola tengo este array mutiple he logrado solo leer hasta listAsientos y quiero acceder a los demas listFichas y listFolios y etc. No logro imprimirlos.
Espero alguna ayuda de ustedes gracias.

Este es lo que me regresa de una api en json

```
{"listarAsientosResponse":{"asientos":{"transaccion":27040,"nroTotalPag":25,"listAsientos":[{"idImgAsiento":74301628,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":25,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":63502948,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":24,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":52056879,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":23,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":43982671,"numPag":2,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":[{"nroPagRef":21,"pagina":1},{"nroPagRef":22,"pagina":2}]},{"idImgAsiento":42850679,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":20,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850678,"numPag":2,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":[{"nroPagRef":18,"pagina":1},{"nroPagRef":19,"pagina":2}]},{"idImgAsiento":42850677,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":17,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850676,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":16,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850675,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":15,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850674,"numPag":4,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":[{"nroPagRef":11,"pagina":1},{"nroPagRef":12,"pagina":2},{"nroPagRef":13,"pagina":3},{"nroPagRef":14,"pagina":4}]},{"idImgAsiento":42850673,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":10,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850672,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":9,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850671,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":8,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850670,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":7,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850669,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":6,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":42850668,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":5,"pagina":1}}],"listFichas":{"idImgFicha":8938361,"numPag":2,"tipo":"FICHA","listPag":[{"nroPagRef":3,"pagina":1},{"nroPagRef":4,"pagina":2}]},"listFolios":[{"idImgFolio":8058883,"nroPagRef":2,"pagina":1,"tipo":"FOLIO"},{"idImgFolio":8058884,"nroPagRef":1,"pagina":1,"tipo":"FOLIO"}]}}}
```

Codigo de recorrido del json

```
$url= file_get_contents("URL JSON");
$mObjeto1= json_decode($url,true);

foreach ($mObjeto1['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listAsientos'] as $asientos1) {
    echo $asientos1["idImgAsiento"]."<br>";
    echo $asientos1["numPag"]."<br>";
    echo $asientos1["tipo"]."<br>";
    echo $asientos1["listPag"]["nroPagRef"]."<br>";
    echo $asientos1["listPag"]["pagina"]."<br>";    
}

foreach ($mObjeto1['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listFichas'] as $asientos) {
    echo $asientos["idImgFicha"]."<br>";
    echo $asientos["tipo"]."<br>";
    echo $asientos["listPag"]["nroPagRef"]."<br>";
    echo $asientos["listPag"]["pagina"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `listFichas` no es un arreglo, es un objeto.

Comment: Lo leo como objeto igual no me recorre.

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a los elementos de tu JSON una vez se ha convertido a un objeto es muy facil:

```
 $mObjeto1= json_decode($url);

$var1= $mObjeto1->listarAsientosResponse->asientos->listAsientos;
```

Aqui has accedido al elemento listAsientos que tiene una array de datos, para acceder al siguiente array:

```
 $var2= $mObjeto1->listarAsientosResponse->asientos->listFichas;
```

Aqui ya puedes recorrerrlo para acceder a cada elemento.

```
 foreach ($var1 as $key => $value) {
   echo "idImgFicha=".$value->idImgAsiento."<br>";
   echo "numPag=".$value->numPag."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Intente hacerlo así pero igual no logro recorrerlo amigo

Comment: Con este codigo me funciona el listAsientos bien

Comment: ```foreach ($var1 as $datos1) {
   echo $datos1->idImgAsiento."<br>";
   echo $datos1->numPag."<br>";
   echo $datos1->tipo."<br>";
   echo $datos1->listPag->nroPagRef."<br>";
   echo $datos1->listPag->pagina."<br>";
}```

Comment: Pero el resto hago con esto pero no recorre sale vacio: foreach ($var2 as $datos2) {
   echo $datos2->idImgFicha."<br>";
   echo $datos2->numPag."<br>";
   echo $datos2->tipo."<br>";
   echo $datos2->listPag->nroPagRef."<br>";
   echo $datos2->listPag->pagina."<br>";
}

Comment: alli te agregue la forma de reccorrerlo

Comment: Si con eso funciona el primero listAsientos pero el resto sale en blanco amigo.

Comment: He logrado recorrer listasientos, listfolios pero listfichas sale en blanco amigo alguna sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes recorrer `lstFichas` por que es un objeto.
Un objeto no se puede recorrer a menos que implemente la interfaz `Iterator` ó haya una función con *generadores*.

A menos que hagas un *cast* a *array*, podrías recorrer **propiedades** visibles y que no sean *int*, aplican algunas reglas de acceso:

```
foreach ((array)$mObjeto1['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listFichas'] as $asientos)
```